# Why i keep getting bootloader error whentrying to dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, grub, boot-loader, hp

So i'm using HP 280 G3 MT. I try to dual boot with Windows 10 and Linux. I have tried to do this with Linux Mint before, and i get `Unable to install GRUB` fatal error. When i restarted my PC, i get this:
[image]

I can't boot to my windows nor Linux. I try to change Linux Mint with Lubuntu, and hoping for better luck but, it still the same. On installation i got:

[image]

I try to enable Legacy mode
[image]

And try to reinstall lubuntu but nothing happened. Anyone know about why this happenned and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you install Linux Mint before installing Windows 10?

Comment: No, i already have windows 10 @NasirRiley

Comment: After installing Windows 10, did you actually install Linux Mint or have you been trying to install it?

Comment: Legacy mode is very unlikely to be the answer. You appear to be trying to install Mint in UEFI mode which is very likely to be the correct mode for your Windows 10 installation. Do you have an efi partition and how full is it?